# BigQuery table performance loss with TABLE_QUERY

Tags: google-bigquery

Having a surprising performance hit when querying multiple tables, vs. one big one.  Scenario:

We have a simple web analytics tool based on BigQuery.  We track basic events for individual sites.  For about a month, we pumped all data into one big table.  Now, we are breaking the data into partitions by SITE and MONTH.

So the big table was simply `[events.all]`

Now we have, say, `[events.events_2014_06_SITEID]`

Querying individual tables for a certain group **is** much faster, and processing much less data.  But querying our entire dataset is much, much slower on even simple queries.  And our new dataset is only 1 day old, whereas the big table is 30 days old, so it's slower despite querying far less data.

For example:

`select count(et) from [events.all] where et='re'`
--> completed in 3.2s, processing 79mb of data.  This table has 21,048,979 rows.

`select count(et) from ( TABLE_QUERY(events, 'table_id CONTAINS "events_2014_"') ) where et='re'`
--> completed in 44.2s, processing 1.8mb of data.  Put together, these tables have 492,264 rows.

How come this occurs, and is there any way to resolve this big disparity?

Comment: How many tables are involved? Querying might get marginally slower for each additional table involved in the query

Comment: As few as 30 and as many as 100.

Comment: So does this seem right?  That # of tables, with a low amount of data, taking that much longer to query?

Comment: exactly - the processing time will increase proportionally to how many tables are being queried